# Awk - Printing n last, interspersed lines containing keyword

Tags: bash, text, awk, reverse, tac

Assume a multi-line text file `file`, with some lines beginning with the keyword `baz`.

```
$ cat file
foo bar
baz qux   # line to be deleted
foo bar
foo bar baz
baz
baz qux quux
foo bar
```

How do I display all those lines not starting with the keyword as well as the `n` last lines starting with the keyword?

If *n=2*, the result should look like this:

```
$ sought_command file
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar baz
baz
baz qux quux
foo bar
```

I believe that *awk* may be the way to go here. Something along the lines of:

```
counter=1
tac file | awk '{
if ($1 =="baz" && counter<=2)
    {print $0; counter=$((counter+1));}
else if ($1 =="baz" && counter>2)
    {next;}
else
    {print $0;}
}' | tac
```

What do I need to change in my above code to make this work?

Comment: How would this logic work? the last few lines still start with `baz`? Is it possible are you referring to one half and the other half

Comment: Awk has no idea that there is a Bash variable also named `counter`.

Comment: @Inian The output is supposed to contain exactly two lines starting with the keyword, namely the last two baz-starting lines of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate or access your Bash variables from Awk, any more than you can access a variable inside a C program from Bash.

```
tac file |
awk '$1 =="baz" && ++counter<=2 {print; next}
     $1 !="baz"' |
tac
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that awk cannot read shell variables. That being said, your suggested code does not print only the last n lines starting with the keyword. Instead, it duplicates the last line starting with the keyword. Can you revise it?

Comment: Sorry about that, removed the offending line break.  This is really just a refactoring of your script so I was too lazy to actually test.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tac file | awk '$1!="baz" || c++<2' | tac
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar baz
baz
baz qux quux
foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try Perl, here is a standalone solution.

```
$ cat michael.txt
foo bar
baz qux   # line to be deleted
foo bar
foo bar baz
baz
baz qux quux
foo bar
$ perl -0777 -ne ' $x++ for(/^baz/gm); $y=$x-2; while( $y-- ) { s/^baz.+?\n//m } ; print ' michael.txt
foo bar
foo bar
foo bar baz
baz
baz qux quux
foo bar
$
```